# Making sure 2 fields are identical

Tags: sugarcrm

Hey I have a module for data entry.

I am looking to make sure that two fields are identical before allowing to save. If they don't match (similar to how website make sure email are same before submit) I want it to say something like "Make sure these two fields match" and not saving until they do.

How do I do this? This is the only thing stoppping me from rolling this module out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can pull this off pretty easily.

Let's say that you want to confirm the following two fields match:

```
username_c
```

and

```
username_compare_c
```

Create a javascript file in the module directory named force_username_compare.js and add the following code to it:

```
addToValidateComparison('EditView', 'username_c', '', true, 'Compare Test', 'username_compare_c');
```

Then you'll need to spit that js out from the view.edit for your module. Assuming you do not have a custom view.edit setup yet create the following file and add this code:
custom/modules/YOUR_MODULE_NAME/views/view.edit.php

```
class YOUR_MODULE_NAMEViewEdit extends ViewEdit
{
    public function display()
    {
        // make sure it works in the subpanel too
        $this->useForSubpanel = true;

        // definitely need to call the parent method
        parent::display();

        // make sure to echo this out AFTER parent::display() call
        echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="custom/modules/YOUR_MODULE_NAME/force_username_compare.js"></script>';
    }
}
```

The addToValidateComparison will take care of all the hardwork for you including preventing the record save if the fields do not match. The 'Compare Test' argument is the message to display when the fields do NOT match. Go ahead and change that to whatever ya like.

**Final Note:** Here is a good article on all the different ways to get some javascript into your view: https://www.atcoresystems.com/blog/adding-custom-javascript-to-a-sugarcrm-view. I used the view controller approach because we do not want our javascript to run until after the fields are present in the DOM and I didn't feel like writing about whether or not jquery and thus the document.ready method was readily accessible.